# Pcolorfast image/array rotation

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, rotation

I have the code below:

```
fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()
graph = ax.pcolorfast(data, cmap='viridis', vmin = min, vmax = max)
pyplot.colorbar(graph)
pyplot.show()
```

and it plots what I wanted, however it is sideways. Is there a good way of rotating it -90 or 270 degrees? I have tried `a.T`, which returns the original plot. I have also tried `ndimage.rotate(graph, -90|270)`, `ndimage.interpolation.rotate(graph, -90|270)`, and `numpy.rot90(data,3)`. The first two return errors for invalid rotation planes and the second appears to shove the graph off the edge, losing a majority of my data points.

If anyone has some thoughts, I would be very grateful. Even if it's that I put in the wrong arguments. I am at a loss here.

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier to know *why* you want it rotated, or what do you expect to obtain. I think it might be easier to change the data and/or the axes than the finished figure. As @Kristof says in their answer, the transpose works perfectly here.

Answer (score 0):

Is `a` supposed to be equal to `data` in your example? Tried your code with a random 2D array, and `np.transpose(a)` as well as `a.T` seem to properly rotate the figure, as opposed to what you indicate here ('returns the original plot'). If this is not the case for you, I think we need more information.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I used `a.T` in my question instead of `data.T` because that was what I was looking at example wise. However, in my actual code the transpose does not change the plot at all.

Comment: Since the plot is scaled, I was actually looking at a 'heatmap' type of thing. The problem is, I want to look at heat vs. time instead of time vs. heat (y,x instead of x,y). I thought `data.T` should work, but it just gave it back to me in the same positions. Does that make it more clear?

Comment: What does `data` represent? Is it a 2D array? What is time supposed to be? I do not understand why a transpose does not change a thing in the example you provide here. 
Have you tried using the fully specified `pcolorfast(x,y,z)` instead of feeding `data` directly in the plotting function?

Comment: I have it working now, but I cannot understand why. I saved the data into a file to be accessed at any time. In a different function, I pulled from this file to plot. Saving a transpose didn't change the image, but transposing the data right before plotting did. Can you please explain why this happened? I do not understand why a command in one place works, but that same does not in another.

Comment: @SanticL You should put *as much information as you can* into the question itself rather than have extended comment discussions.

Comment: @Kristof Right now this is not actually an answer, if you work this out make sure that you change it to be a real answer or it may well be deleted.

Comment: @Ajean If I knew what questions would be asked, I would. Unfortunately, I am not clairvoyant and cannot predict what different coders like to look at to solve problems. I do attempt to provide all the options I have already attempted, so as not to back track. Thank you.

Comment: @SanticL No need to get tetchy, I just meant that you should *edit* your question to include the additional info you've provided in these comments, which helps other folks who may run across the question.

Comment: @Ajean I agree that this should either be deleted in the end, or edited to a real answer. Problem is that I could not respond in any other way since I do not have sufficient reputation to post a comment on a question...

Comment: @SanticL still difficult to track the problem without your lines of code. Would it be possible to post your lines in the original question, including what works and what doesn't? Maybe we can track it down and get you a real answer.

Comment: @Ajean I did not mean to come off as mean and I am sorry that it appeared that way. I did not think my comments added much to the question, but I will keep that in mind for future questions.

Comment: @Kristof Unfortunately, this is all I can post without putting all of my code on and my place of work doesn't allow me to do that. The most I can say is what I already have. :( I'm sorry.

Comment: @Ajean Could you then maybe just indicate what you mean by "Saving a transpose didn't change the image". Just give an example of how you did it when you found out it didn't work.

Comment: @SanticL You still missed my point. Did you know you can edit youth question? The little edit button underneath it. You wrote some additional info in comments. Put that same info into the question. Also, I think Kristof meant to notify you in the last comment instead of me :)